# MessageBox closed event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MessageBox only with `Ok` button, although there's close button. But in code I can check only `DialogResult.Ok`.
How should I check which button user had pressed?
Only as `if (MessageBox("error") != DialogResult.Ok)` or there's another way?
Is any event, that occures, when user closes MessageBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this way,

```
 DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Message", "Tests", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
 {

 }
 else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
 {

 }
```